# das ist vs. es ist

Tags: difference, word-choice, phrase, pronoun, expression

When do you use "das ist" instead of "es ist"?

In questions is "das ist" more commonly used?  I don't understand when to use "es ist" and when to use "das ist" in sentences and questions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. In its current form, your question is extremely broad, and would probably get closed. Maybe you can add odd examples of which sentences you have problems with? Do you maybe think that you could derive any kind of rule from the examples you give? That would be good starting points for good answers.

Comment: Related/duplicate... http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9593/when-to-use-the-anticipatory-es-das/9594#9594

Comment: I voted "reopen" because I think it's a dupe

Comment: @Emanuel: I think it's impossible to tell whether this is a duplicate or not until the asker has supplied us with sufficient information so we know how to interpret the question. I would like to encourage all once again to attempt to improve the question by adding examples, context etc.

Answer (score 6):

"das ist" = "this (or that) is", "es ist" = "it is". Use as in English.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please? Der and Die are this too?

Comment: *Der/Die/Das* are like "the" (but with gender). *Diese*(-s/-n/-r/-m/..) is more like "this", demonstrative. But yeah, he didn't answer when to use which; and often germans use "Das" (This) while in English one would use "it" (Es). That's what is unclear and needs to be explained.